# Insert image into binary field MySQL, NodeJS

Tags: mysql, node.js

First of all, i understand that storing images into DB is a bad practice, however i need to do it.
I have a table in MySQL (..., img BINARY, ..) and have some images on my machine.
How should I transform my input data, to make it avaliable  store in BINARY field? And how to decode it into original format again?